# Replace value of variable directly inside f-string

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

I'm trying to replace a value inside a variable that I use within an f-string. In this case it is a single quote. For example:

```
var1 = "foo"
var2 = "bar '"

print(f"{var1}-{var2}")
```

Now, I want to get rid of the single quote within var2, but do it directly in the print statement. I've tried:

```
print(f"{var1}-{var2.replace("'","")}")
```

which gives me: EOL while scanning string literal.

I do not want to impose a third variable, so no var3 = var2.replace(",","") etc...

I would rather not use a regex, but if there is no other way, please tell me how to do it.

What is the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the contents contains both `'` and `"`, you can use a *triple* quoted string:

```
>>> print(f'''{var1}-{var2.replace("'","")}''')
foo-bar
```

Comment: oh wow, that's both the easiest and fastest solution I've ever gotten. Thank you so much!

Comment: Bonus: Triple quoted strings can span multiple lines and keep the newline character in the string.

Comment: You can nest one layer further, since you have access to both single and double triple quoted strings. That being said, this is probably a moment when you should step back and ask yourself if you ever plan on being able to read this code in the future.

Comment: @Matthias that I knew and already use, but just couldn't wrap my head around it why I need 3 quotes for such a replace (and still can't but hey it works :))

Comment: @JVGBI. Because you can't escape things in an f-string